# Импортирую библиотеки selenium и pathlib, pyCharm выдает предупреждения

Tags: python, selenium, pathlib

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

> И pyCharm выдает предупреждения, хотя библиотеки установленв

```
Unused import statement 'import pathlib'  
Unused import statement 'from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select'  
Unused import statement 'from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys'  
Unused import statement 'from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains'
```

Как исправить?

Comment: убрать импорты, потому что `pyCharm` вам говорит о том, что вы не используйте эти импорты. зачем тогда их (модули) импортировать ?

Comment: cпасибо, мне нужно pyCharm лучше изучить. Как вам тут респект кидать, за то что помог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрать эи импорты, потому что pyCharm вам говорит о том, что вы не используйте эти импорты: `Unused import statement`